# Adding filters to SQL query (ORACLE database)

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to list tables, columns and their data type; I used this code:

```
select TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE 
from dba_tab_columns 
order by TABLE_NAME;
```

The problem is that the database is too large and I only need 2000 specific table/column/datatype. Knowing that a table with the same name and column can be present in multiple SCHEMA

For example (I have 2000 lines like that table names are very random and have nothing in common so is the case for the column names):

```
TABLE            Column           SCHEMA
------------------------------------------
DMT_AAAAAAA        C1111          ANT_A1
DMT_AAAAAAA        C1111          ANT_A2
BBBBBBBB           A4444          ANT_A3
JHD6365            H5525          ZUGRU
WRK679             C3020          MUSTSU
TDG5378            C66739         SHGUY
```

I tried to filter by schema using this query :

```
select TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE 
from dba_tab_columns 
where OWNER in ('ANT_A1', 'ANT_A2', 'ANT_A1', 'ZUGRU', 'MUSTSU', 'SHGUY') 
order by TABLE_NAME;
```

The issue now is that it lists all columns even the ones I don't need.

Is there a way to filter out only the lines needed?

Expected output :

```
|table name   |   column    |  data type|
DMT_AAAAAAA        C1111          NUMBER
DMT_AAAAAAA        C1111          VARCHAR
BBBBBBBB           A4444          NUMBER
JHD6365            H5525          VARCHAR
WRK679             C3020          VARCHAR
TDG5378            C66739         VARCHAR
```

Thank you.

Comment: Query and get distinct data that you need in to separate tables. Remove the unwanted data in those, Then join those with the main table

Comment: I don't understand your issue. You only want certain schemas, so you use `owner in (...)`. Now you want only certain columns, too, so why don't you just add a condition `column_name in (...)`?

Comment: How can you expect this output? You select schemas ANT_A1 and ANT_A2, but your result contains tables from other schemas (ZUGRU, MUSTSU, ...).

Comment: @ThorstenKettner the column names are very random i gave a wrong example, i edited it the names are really random ( i Added few examples )

Comment: @Srinika to be honest i didn't understand the idea you gave me i'm really new to oracle and sql like 2 days ago ^_^

Comment: @ThorstenKettner i need to have the datatype of each column to know if it's a CHAR VARCHAR2 … and so on the database contains like 10 years Worth of data and the list i have contains a table of |TABLENAME|COLUMN|SCHEMA| that i need to specify its datatype. (sorry if my explaination isn't clear i'm new to this)

Comment: Okay, so what you are showing is the list of columns you want to see. Please see my answer; this should work for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to show the information about certain columns across schemas and tables, specify them in an `IN` clause using tuples:

```
select owner, table_name, column_name, data_type
from dba_tab_columns 
where (owner, table_name, column_name) in 
(
  ('DMT_AAAAAAA', 'C1111', 'ANT_A1'),
  ('DMT_AAAAAAA', 'C1111', 'ANT_A2'),
  ('BBBBBBBB', 'A4444', 'ANT_A3'),
  ('JHD6365', 'H5525', 'ZUGRU'),
  ('WRK679', 'C3020', 'MUSTSU'),
  ('TDG5378', 'C66739', 'SHGUY')
)
order by owner, table_name, column_name;
```

Comment: returns this error:

ERROR at line 4:
ORA-00920: invalid relational operator

Comment: Small typo, should be `column_name` not `column, name`. But thanks, Thorsten, you understood the question. I'll delete my answer, then, ok?

Comment: @wolφi: Thank you for pointing out my mistake. Stupid me, I could just have tried the query before posting it :-)

Comment: @Tarik MESSAOUDI: I've corrected the typo in my query.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I wouldn't call anybody stupid, and thanks for pointing out the IN ((a,b,c)) syntax!

Comment: Then you are doing something wrong. Maybe a comma too many or the like. Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=559df47087216d291bd00a91d03bd3fa (I had to change the table name to all_tab_columns, because in that fiddle I have no access to dba_tab_columns.)

Answer (score 1):

Check whether the following is enough. (I'm considering your output only)

```
select Distinct TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE from dba_tab_columns
```

If you don't want the tables, 'BBBBBBBB' and 'WRK679'

Put those in to a table (say tblExclude) and you can use the following

```
select Distinct TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE from dba_tab_columns a
Left Join tblExclude b on a.TABLE_NAME = b.TABLE_NAME
Where b.TABLE_NAME is null
```

Comment: it shows up the output as needed yet the problem i have is filtering the tables/columns i need if not i will have the output of the complete database and it's too long

Comment: So that is why my earlier suggestion comes in.
Say you need to get all distinct tables, you can get those by 
select Distinct TABLE_NAME  from dba_tab_columns. Execute that and get the results, remove unwanted and put to a new table. do the same for the col name if you want to do so. Then join those 2 tables with dba_tab_columns.

Also let me know, whether your needed table/column list is longer than unwanted  table/column list or not

Comment: @Srinika No need for DISTINCT here, table_name, column_name, data_type is already distinct.

Comment: wolφi, are you sure :)

Comment: @Srinika, sorry, didn't see that you don't have owner in the column list...